# Changing JSON.NET property name mapping in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to have my property mapped to a different name when posting data to my API.

```cs
public class SampleModel
{
    [JsonProperty("ugly_name")]     // <- this line using built-in stuff
    public string BeautifulName { get; set; }
}
```

Using MVC 6?

The code above uses `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Just map a custom name (here "ugly_name") with a property - BeautifulName.

Comment: Just so we can rewrite your question... are you trying to change the data binding of properties so that `ugly_name` is mapped to `BeautifulName` when you are posting data to an API?

Comment: @MaximeRouiller exactly :) posting data to an API and receiving data as well.

Comment: Have you tried this code? It should work.

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)? It describes several attributes that can be used if you don't want to use JsonPropertyAttribute.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, any solution on this?